# SQL Server PDO UPDATE loop error

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to write a script to hash some temporary passwords. For now the temporary password and the hashed version are stored in the same table. As soon as I get them hashed, I'm going to drop the unhashed column. **The problem is:** My script is setting all hashed passwords to match the last record in the table.

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=database", "sqlUser", "password");
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT tempPassword FROM employeeTable");
$result->execute();
$sql = "UPDATE employeeTable SET hashTempPass = :tempPass ";

while($data = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
    $tempPass = $data['tempPassword'];  
    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->bindValue(':tempPass', $tempPass);  
    $q->execute();
}
```

Results are as such

```
user1    unhashPass1    hashpass3
user2    unhashPass2    hashpass3
user3    unhashpass3    hashpass3
```

Whereas what I need is

```
user1    unhashPass1    hashPass1
user2    unhashPass2    hashPass2
user3    unhashpass3    hashpass3
```

I hope this question is clear enough. Thank you.

Edit: Since I was struggling with this, **I'm not yet hashing the passwords** until I get this code working.

Comment: Why not use a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Doh... missed the missing WHERE

Comment: I just added [  WHERE tempPassword = :tempPass"; ] to the end of the [ $sql ] statement. Negative affect, code is broken. I'm sure I did it wrong. Also, should the while loop be in a try/catch? If yes, whats the best way to report errors?

Comment: You'd need to add another clause `WHERE tempPassword = :tempPass AND user = :user` type of thing. As for errors, you could add `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened and `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` if that's what you are asking in regards to errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close but you need to change the query:

```
SELECT user, tempPassword FROM employeeTable
```

and

```
UPDATE employeeTable SET hashTempPass = :tempPass WHERE user = :user
```

this will allow you to grab both hash and temp password.

You can then update the table based on the temp password:

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=database", "sqlUser", "password");
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT hash, tempPassword FROM employeeTable");
$result->execute();

//prepare it only once (no need to send query to server at each iteration
$sql = "UPDATE employeeTable SET hashTempPass = :tempPass WHERE user = :user";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);

while($data = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
    $tempPass = $data['tempPassword'];  
    $user = $data['user']; 

    $q->bindValue(':tempPass', $tempPass);  
    $q->bindValue(':user', $user);  

    $q->execute();
}
```

**Note**

- I called the field `user` but you will need to adjust that column
  field to match your table of course.
- `UPDATE` without `WHERE` clause can lead you to the biggest mistake a database admin can do.

Comment: It finally works! Thanks a lot. I don't want to admit how long I was working on that yesterday.